# How to make sum calculations without using atomic in CUDA

Tags: performance, optimization, cuda, sum

In the below code, how can I calculate **sum_array** value without using *atomicAdd*.

Kernel method

```
__global__ void calculate_sum( int width,
                               int height,
                               int *pntrs,
                               int2 *sum_array )
{
    int row = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    int col = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    if ( row >= height || col >= width ) return;

    int idx = pntrs[ row * width + col ];

    //atomicAdd( &sum_array[ idx ].x, col );

    //atomicAdd( &sum_array[ idx ].y, row );

    sum_array[ idx ].x += col;

    sum_array[ idx ].y += row;
}
```

Launch Kernel

```
    dim3 dimBlock( 16, 16 );
    dim3 dimGrid( ( width + ( dimBlock.x - 1 ) ) / dimBlock.x, 
                  ( height + ( dimBlock.y - 1 ) ) / dimBlock.y );
```

Answer (score 1):

Reduction is a general name for this kind of problems. Look at the [presentation](http://www.cse.nd.edu/courses/cse40833/www/kogge_gpu/lectures/logsum.pdf) for further explanation or use Google for other examples.

General way to solve this is to make parallel sum of global memory segments inside the thread blocks and store the results in global memory. Afterwards, copy the partial results to CPU memory space, sum the partial results using CPU, and copy the result back to GPU memory. You can avoid coping of memory by execution of another parallel sum for the partial results.

Another approach is to use highly optimized libraries for CUDA such as Thrust or CUDPP which contain functions doing the stuff.

Answer (score 0):

My Cuda is *very very rusty*, but this is roughly how you do it (courtesy of "Cuda by Example", which I would strongly suggest you to read):

https://developer.nvidia.com/content/cuda-example-introduction-general-purpose-gpu-programming-0

1. Do a better partitioning of the array you need to sum: threads in CUDA are lightweight, but not so much that you can spawn one for just two sums and hope to get any performance benefit in return.
2. At this point each thread will be tasked to sum over a slice of your data: create an array of shared int as big as the number of your threads, where each thread will save the partial sum it computed.
3. Synchronize the threads and reduce the shared memory array:

(please, take it as *pseudocode*)

```
// Code to sum over a slice, essentially a loop over each thread subset
// and accumulate over "localsum" (a local variable)
...

// Save the result in the shared memory
partial[threadidx] = localsum;

// Synchronize the threads:
__syncthreads();

// From now on partial is filled with the result of all computations: you can reduce partial
// we'll do it the illiterate way, using a single thread (it can be easily parallelized)
if(threadidx == 0) {
    for(i = 1; i < nthreads; ++i) {
        partial[0] += partial[i];
    }
}
```

and off you go: partial[0] will hold your sum (or computation).

See the dot product example in "CUDA by example" for a more rigorous discussion of the topic and a reduction algorithm that runs in about O(log(n)).

Hope this helps